# TextField values are dissapeared?

Tags: flutter, input, flutter-layout

I started learning flutter recently. In my app window when I push a button a bottom sheet modal will appear like in the below image. When I typing in the 'Amount' text field, the previously typed 'Title' text filed content is disappeared. Why is this happen and how to solve this?

[image]

This my code related to read text field inputs.

```
import 'dart:io';

import './adaptive_flat_button.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';



class NewTransaction extends StatelessWidget {
  final Function newTransactionHandler;
  
  final titleController = TextEditingController();
  final amountController = TextEditingController();

  DateTime selectedDate;

  NewTransaction(this.newTransactionHandler);


  void addTx() {
    if (amountController.text.isEmpty) {
      return;
    }

    String titileTxt = titleController.text;
    double amount = double.parse(amountController.text);

    if (titileTxt.isEmpty || amount <= 0 || selectedDate == null) {
      return;
    }
    newTransactionHandler(titileTxt, amount, selectedDate);

    Navigator.of(context).pop();
  }

  void presentDatePicker() {
    showDatePicker(
            context: context,
            initialDate: DateTime.now(),
            firstDate: DateTime(2019),
            lastDate: DateTime.now())
        .then((pickedDate) {
      if (pickedDate == null) {
        return;
      }
  
        selectedDate = pickedDate;
     
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Card(
        elevation: 5,
        child: Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(
              top: 10,
              left: 10,
              right: 10,
              bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom + 10),
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
            children: [
              TextField(
                decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Title'),
                controller: titleController,
                onSubmitted: (_) => addTx(),
                // onChanged: (val) {
                //   titleInput = val;
                // },
              ),
              TextField(
                decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Amount'),
                controller: amountController,
                keyboardType: TextInputType.phone,
                onSubmitted: (_) => addTx(),
                // onChanged: (val) {
                //   amountInput = val;
                // },
              ),
              Container(
                height: 70,
                child: Row(
                  children: [
                    Text(selectedDate == null
                        ? 'No date chosen!'
                        : 'PickedDate: ${DateFormat.yMd().format(selectedDate)}'),
                    AdaptiveFlatButton('Choose Date', presentDatePicker),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              RaisedButton(
                color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                textColor: Theme.of(context).textTheme.button.color,
                child: Text(
                  'Add Transaction',
                ),
                onPressed: addTx,
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: why you need onSubmitted? I guess it is because it trigger this   if `(amountController.text.isEmpty) {
      return;
    }`.

Comment: I removed onSubmitted. But I still have that problem.

Comment: removed both ??

Comment: Removed onSubmitted on TextFields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this issue by just replacing StatelessWidget with StatefulWidget.

```
import 'dart:io';

import './adaptive_flat_button.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

class NewTransaction extends StatefulWidget {
  final Function newTransactionHandler;

  NewTransaction(this.newTransactionHandler) {
    print('Constructor NewTRansaction');
  }

  @override
  _NewTransactionState createState() {
    print('CreateState NewTransaction');
    return _NewTransactionState();
  }
}

class _NewTransactionState extends State<NewTransaction> {
  final _titleController = TextEditingController();
  final _amountController = TextEditingController();

  DateTime selectedDate;

  _NewTransactionState() {
    print('Constructor NewTransaction State');
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    print('initState()');
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void didUpdateWidget(covariant NewTransaction oldWidget) {
    // TODO: implement didUpdateWidget
    print('didUpdate()');
    super.didUpdateWidget(oldWidget);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    // TODO: implement dispose
    print('dispose()');
    super.dispose();
  }

  void _addTx() {
    if (_amountController.text.isEmpty) {
      return;
    }

    String titileTxt = _titleController.text;
    double amount = double.parse(_amountController.text);

    if (titileTxt.isEmpty || amount <= 0 || selectedDate == null) {
      return;
    }
    widget.newTransactionHandler(titileTxt, amount, selectedDate);

    Navigator.of(context).pop();
  }

  void _presentDatePicker() {
    showDatePicker(
            context: context,
            initialDate: DateTime.now(),
            firstDate: DateTime(2019),
            lastDate: DateTime.now())
        .then((pickedDate) {
      if (pickedDate == null) {
        return;
      }
      setState(() {
        selectedDate = pickedDate;
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Card(
        elevation: 5,
        child: Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(
              top: 10,
              left: 10,
              right: 10,
              bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom + 10),
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
            children: [
              TextField(
                decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Title'),
                controller: _titleController,
                onSubmitted: (_) => _addTx(),
                // onChanged: (val) {
                //   titleInput = val;
                // },
              ),
              TextField(
                decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Amount'),
                controller: _amountController,
                keyboardType: TextInputType.phone,
                onSubmitted: (_) => _addTx(),
                // onChanged: (val) {
                //   amountInput = val;
                // },
              ),
              Container(
                height: 70,
                child: Row(
                  children: [
                    Text(selectedDate == null
                        ? 'No date chosen!'
                        : 'PickedDate: ${DateFormat.yMd().format(selectedDate)}'),
                    AdaptiveFlatButton('Choose Date', _presentDatePicker),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              RaisedButton(
                color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                textColor: Theme.of(context).textTheme.button.color,
                child: Text(
                  'Add Transaction',
                ),
                onPressed: _addTx,
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `setState` in **Stateless Widget**

Just refractor with right click on `StatelessWidget`, select **refractor** then select **Convert to StatefulWidget**